# reading and writing to a pipe c issue

Tags: c, pipe, fork

Here is the program:

```
  int fd[2];
  char buf1 [31];
  int i;
  char buf2;

  pipe(fd);

  if (fork() == 0) { // child
    close(fd[1]); // close writing pipe
    for(i = 0; i< 20; i++) { 
        read(fd[0], buf1, 30);
        printf("%s\n", buf1);

    }
    close(fd[0]);
  }

  else { // parent
    close(fd[0]); // close reading end
    buf2 = 'a';
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        write(fd[1], &buf2, sizeof(buf2));
    }
    close(fd[1]);
  }
  wait(NULL);
```

Since read blocks if there is nothing in there, we will first write to the pipe.

My question is regarding the **write** function. The for loop runs 20 times, and each time I am writing an `a` to the pipe. After 20 iterations, the pipe on write end will contains `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

In the child, I read all 20 `a's` into `buf1`, and I print the result.

**Now is the pipe empty, since we have wrote, and read what we wrote?**

Since there is also a for loop here, we read again, but this time, I think the pipe is empty, so theres nothing to read. So I think the final output after 20 iterations of reading is just 
`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

But actually it's this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Why? Is the pipe not empty after we read?

Comment: You don't clear the buffer after reading data into it, so the data you read the first time are still there when you print the buffer again.  This would be clearer if you checked the return values of your function calls.

Comment: Note also that you fail to append a null terminator after reading the data; it is therefore incorrect to rely upon there being one.  You lucked out on that.  Or maybe not, for if you had used the return value of `read()` (correctly) to determine where the terminator should go, then you would not have been confused.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That depends; this isn’t a MCVE so we don’t know exactly where and how the declaration of `buf1` is happening. If it’s static instead of happening in `main`, or if it has an initialization which wasn’t included here, then the rest of the characters are 0 and it’s safe. If all of this is in `main`, then yeah it could be a problem.

Comment: @DanielH, the declaration of `buf1` is in the code presented.  Second line.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But is it in `main`, or is it at file scope? Based on the indentation, probably `main`, but we don’t know.

Comment: @DanielH, I see no reason to suppose that the source presented consists of concatenation of fragments drawn from separate scopes, as it would need to be for the declarations within to be at file scope.  But you're right that if they *were* at file scope then they would be subject to default initialization.

Comment: @JohnBollinger When people don’t provide MCVEs, they often also don’t specify scope change or other details clearly. I wouldn’t be surprised either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that if the child calls `read` before the parent has written anything, the call will block; however, after the parent closes the file descriptor, this is no longer the case and `read` will return 0 for EOF.

The `read` call doesn’t clear the buffer. The OS successfully reads zero characters, and therefore changes the first zero characters of the buffer. That is, it doesn’t change `buf1` at all. Thus, once all the data has been read into the buffer, the `printf` call will always do the same thing.

Note that you aren’t guaranteed to get this output. It is perfectly possible that the child will be run after some but not all of the `write` calls from the parent, in which case it will not read all 20 `a`s at once and print shorter strings. That’s why above I said that the `printf` call will always do the same thing *once all the data has been read*. To handle the case where not all the data has been written, you should check the return value of `read`. If it is less than 20 you didn’t read the full string into the buffer (and should call `read` again with the destination pointer advanced so you don’t overwrite your data); if it is zero then you’ve reached end-of-file (the write end is closed); if it is negative there was an error and you should check `errno` to handle it.

Comment: So are you saying that in the first read call, read reads all 20 a's, and after that, since the pipe is empty, it does not read anymore, hence it does not change the buffer. so 20a's are printed 20 times

Comment: Yes. Although that’s just luck; you could get the first `read` call reading 3 `a`s, and printing that, the second `read` call reading the remaining 17 `a`s and printing 17 `a`s (since it overwrote the first three), and the remaining read calls all doing 17 `a`s.

Comment: okay, thank you. but also i have one more question. I understand then when you write to a pipe, first we wrote an `a`, then we wrote another `a`, now we have `aa`, and when we read, hopefully, we read `aa` back. I experiemented and instead of `a`, I decided to write `hello`, and then `hello` again. So I assume on the pipe we have `hellohello`, but actually, when I read (just one read call), only `hello` is printed, not `hellohello`. Why could this be?

Comment: For the same reason as in my previous example. If the `read` happened before the second `write`, then it’ll just see `hello`. Fortunately if you’re writing a small amount of data (`PIPE_BUF` bytes, probably 4096), the writes are atomic and you won’t get `hellohe`, but if you had large writes you might.

Comment: How would I check the return value. I could do: `if (read(fd[0], buf1, 30) != 11)` ... how do I "reread", since the pipe will have lost its data

Comment: @KSplitX The pipe only “loses” the data that has been read. If you read 5 bytes from the pipe, then it will lose 5 bytes and the next time you `read` from it it will have all the rest. The way to do it is to make a variable, `ssize_t count`, and do `count = read(fd[0], buf1, 30); if (count == 0) { /* Handle EOF */ } else if (count == -1) { /* Handle error */ } else { /* Handle having read count bytes of data */ };`. If you do that in a loop, and instead of passing `buf1` you pass a pointer which you increase on successful read, you can read all the data without losing any.